# how to perform Neoload proxy settings?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, neoload

How to set the proxy for neoload test tool as well as in mobile device
then how to establish the connection between the device and the tool

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the Identify as to target mobile device and start recording[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't works using the above method. Try recording in Tunnel mode.
http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#5666.htm